# Onload-script not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm writing a customer form, where a drop down menu should be automatically set to the appropriate option if the `window.top.document.url` is known.

To achieve this I do a `<body onload='javascript:init([Generic value])'` which calls

> ```
> function init(value) {
>      if (value) {
>           document.getElementById('RefererURL').value = window.top.document.URL;
>           form1.submit();
>        }
>    }
> ```

I don't remember why we added the `if(value)` thing, but the rest is pretty straight forward - get the value, then submit the form to trigger an update that does the actual url-menu mappning.

This solution works in IE, but not in Firefox, and I can't figure out why. I'm suspecting it might have something to do with `form1.submit();`, but don't understand what or why.

Comment: I just realized my question subject lacks a negation. :)

Comment: You shouldn't start event handler attributes with `javascript:`. It's unnecessary and only doesn't cause an error by coincidence (it happens to be valid JavaScript syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

> document.getElementById("form1").submit();

This assumes your form id is 'form1'.

Comment: Nice start to the day for me a hero ;)